# How to customize Indicator styling with com.glide.slider.library.SliderLayout?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, slider, android-glide

I have the following Slider Layout using [this slider](https://github.com/firdausmaulan/GlideSlider):

```
                <com.glide.slider.library.SliderLayout
                    android:id="@+id/slider_product_image"
                    android:layout_width="500dp"
                    android:layout_height="350dp"/>
                <com.glide.slider.library.indicators.PagerIndicator
                    android:id="@+id/custom_indicator"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:selected_height="20dp"
                    app:selected_width="20dp"/>
```

Here's the code I use to set it up:

```
            //Slider
            for (item in prod.images) {
                val sliderView = DefaultSliderView(context)

                // initialize SliderLayout
                sliderView
                    .image(item)
                    .setRequestOption(
                        RequestOptions()
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                            .skipMemoryCache(true)
                    )
                binding.sliderProductImage.addSlider(sliderView)
            }
            binding.sliderProductImage.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom)
            binding.sliderProductImage.stopCyclingWhenTouch(false)
            binding.sliderProductImage.stopAutoCycle()
```

The slider is based on [this one using picasso as image loader](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider). The original slider allows for thorough indicator customization as can be seen [here](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/wiki/Custom-Indicators). There are available properties such as `app:selected_height` and `app:selected_width`, which are supposed to set the height and width of the indicator of the selected item, but they don't have any effect on the layout itself. Here's an image of my result:

[image]

The selected indicator is still the same size. Am I missing something? Is there a way to apply these properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my error... All the way at the bottom it says [you need to bind it with a SliderLayout instance](http://slider.setCustomIndicator((PagerIndicator)%20findViewById(R.id.custom_indicator));) for it to work:

```
binding.sliderProductImage.setCustomIndicator(custom_indicator as PagerIndicator)
```